# Why does this split not work?

Tags: python, text-files

Why does this split not work? When I run the code `split_1` is not printed.

```
with open ('r_3exp', 'a+') as file_1:
 choice = input ('1 (write) or 2? ')
 number = input ('What number?')

 if choice == '1':
    file_1.write ('\n') 
    file_1.write ('Here are some numbers : 1233 8989' + ' ' + number)
 else:
    for line in file_1:
        split_1 = line.split (":")
        print (split_1)
```

Comment: Are you using Python 3 or 2.7? As of right now, the reason it doesn't work (in Python 2.7) is because nothing is being written to the file `r_3exp`, and that's tied to the fact that `input()` evaluates user input as valid Python, while `raw_input()` returns a string.

Comment: Python 3 and, also, the 1 has already been selected, meaning that the file has been written to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are opening your file up in `a+` mode.

`a+` allows for *both* reading and appending to a file. On the surface, this sounds ideal for what you want. However, there are some subtle tricky mechanics you've missed about this mode:

- [A file opened in `a+` is automatically opened at the *end* of the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466000/python-open-built-in-function-difference-between-modes-a-a-w-w-and-r). In other words, you are no longer reading from the *beginning* of the file, but rather starting from the very end of it.
- As a consequence, when you do `for line in file_1`, you are actually starting to read from the character at the very end of the file. Since there is, by definition, nothing there, `line` returns an empty string and `line.split(':')` is also empty.

To correct this, it is more prudent to reorganise your code a little to use *either* `r` mode or `a` mode:

```
choice = input("1 (write) or 2? ")
if choice == "1":
    number = input("What number? ")
    with open("r_3exp","a") as file_1:
        file_1.write ('\n') 
        file_1.write ('Here are some numbers : 1233 8989' + ' ' + number)
elif choice == "2":
    with open("r_3exp","r") as file_1:
        for line in file_1:
            split_1 = line.split (":")
            print (split_1)
```

`r` opens up your file to start reading from the first character of the file, rather than from the last.

---

I would still recommend the above code for someone using Python 2.7, but with one additional caveat: `input()` returns `None` in Python 2.7, because it's actually *evaluating* the input as a Python command. The correct function to use in Python 2.7 is `raw_input()`, which correctly returns a string.